# How to use queue in different function?

Tags: c++, c, queue

The items in the queues keep resetting. How can I display all the items in the queues after choosing the Display function in the main menu? If I choose the Display function after I put the items using the "Add Items" Function, it doesn't display the items that I put. How can I display all the items in the queues after choosing the Display function in the main menu?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "linkedQueue.h"

using namespace std;

void mainMenu();
void addQueues();
void Display();

int main()
{
    mainMenu();
    system("pause>0");
    return 0;
}

void mainMenu()
{
    system("cls");
    int num;
    linkedQueueType<int> queue;
    cout << "\t\t\t OPERATIONS";
    cout << "\n\n  [1] Add items";
    cout << "\n  [2] Delete items";
    cout << "\n  [3] Show the number of items";
    cout << "\n  [4] Show min and max items";
    cout << "\n  [5] Find an item";
    cout << "\n  [6] Sort items";
    cout << "\n  [7] Print all items";
    cout << "\n  [8] Exit";

    cout << " \n\n Enter choice: ";
    cin >> num;
    switch (num)
    {
    case 1:

        int x;
        char ch;
        cout << "\nAdd number: ";
        cin >> x;
        queue.addQueue(x);
        cout << "Enter again? (Y/N)     ";
        cin >> ch;
        while (ch == 'Y')
        {
            cout << "\nAdd number: ";
            cin >> x;
            queue.addQueue(x);
            cout << "Enter again? (Y/N)     ";
            cin >> ch;
        }
        if (ch == 'N')
        {
            mainMenu();
        }
        break;

    case 7:

        cout << "Queue Elements: ";

        if (queue.isEmptyQueue())
            cout << "Queue is empty - add item first\n";
        else
        {
            while (!queue.isEmptyQueue())
            {
                cout << queue.front() << " ";
                queue.deleteQueue();
            }
        }

    break;

    default:
        cout << "Invalid" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any cout in deleteQueue() ? Other than that there is no print statement in your program to display the items in the Queue .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the recursive call to mainMenu() function due to which queue is initialized again and again. TO avoid this you can initialize num to 0 as `num=0` after that use a while loop inside mainmenu() and put your code inside while loop

```
#include <iostream>
#include "linkedQueue.h"
using namespace std;
void mainMenu();
void addQueues();
void Display();

int main()
{
mainMenu();
system("pause>0");
return 0;
}

void mainMenu()
{
system("cls");
int num=0;
linkedQueueType<int> queue;
while(num!=8)
{
cout << "\t\t\t OPERATIONS";
cout << "\n\n  [1] Add items";
cout << "\n  [2] Delete items";
cout << "\n  [3] Show the number of items";
cout << "\n  [4] Show min and max items";
cout << "\n  [5] Find an item";
cout << "\n  [6] Sort items";
cout << "\n  [7] Print all items";
cout << "\n  [8] Exit";

cout << " \n\n Enter choice: ";
cin >> num;
switch (num)
{
case 1:

    int x;
    char ch;
    cout << "\nAdd number: ";
    cin >> x;
    queue.addQueue(x);
    cout << "Enter again? (Y/N)     ";
    cin >> ch;
    while (ch == 'Y')
    {
        cout << "\nAdd number: ";
        cin >> x;
        queue.addQueue(x);
        cout << "Enter again? (Y/N)     ";
        cin >> ch;
    }
    break;

case 7:

    cout << "Queue Elements: ";

    if (queue.isEmptyQueue())
        cout << "Queue is empty - add item first\n";
    else
    {
        while (!queue.isEmptyQueue())
        {
            cout << queue.front() << " ";
            queue.deleteQueue();
        }
    }

break;

default:
    cout << "Invalid" << endl;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the recursive call to mainMenu() function.  As in

```
if (ch == 'N')
{
    mainMenu();
}
```

Each time you enter a mainMenu() function a new queue will be created on the function stack, so it will not contain elements from the previous function calls.  You may want to initialize your queue in the main() function (or somewhere else) and then pass it as a parameter to the mainMenu() function.

Comment: Is there a way to display the Main Menu after adding items to the queue by not doing 

    if (ch == 'N')
    {
        mainMenu();
    }
?